# Parsing JSON with paragraph breaks in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift

My app grabs a JSON and then parses it to populate the UITableView and the detail view data. One of these fields is designed to contain descriptions, and many of them include paragraph breaks. How should I encode the JSON to include paragraph breaks?

(I am creating the JSON, so I can enter whatever into the JSON file. I'm hoping that there is a way to enter it in JSON that will be processed automatically via the Swift 4 JSONDecoder() method).

Comment: Do you mean HTML? or just new lines to create paragraphs

Comment: Post your both the json and the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent newline symbols with escaped character `\\n`. Here's an example of decoding such string:

```
struct Entity: Codable {
  var title: String
  var desc: String
}

let testJson = """
{
  "title": "Title",
  "desc": "first row,\\nsecond row,\\n\\nthird row"
}
"""
let testData = testJson.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
  let entity = try JSONDecoder().decode(Entity.self, from: testData)
  print(entity)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```